# Failed to add PW_USER_PASSWORD attribute

Tags: c++, freeradius

`rc_avpair_add` is continuously failing at the below line.

```
if (rc_avpair_add(rh, &send, PW_USER_PASSWORD, passwd, -1, 0) == NULL)
```

What will be the possible issue? or How to view the reason for the failure. Password I have given is `"admin"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally resolved the issue by deleting "dictionary" file from the working directory